# BottomSheetDialog comes over android navigation footer

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, dialogfragment, bottom-sheet

The enter animation for the bottom sheet I am using comes over the bottom sheet navigation footer (the thing with the back, home and processes buttons).

It's important to note that the fragment's layout is a RecyclerView

Can anyone help?

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
  @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
RecyclerView rootView =
    (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_quick_actions_container, container, true);
rootView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
rootView.setAdapter(new QuickActionsAdapter(inflater, mQuickActionListItems, this));
return rootView;
```

}

```
  @Override public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    int height = -1; // MATCH_PARENT
    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.quick_action_list_item_width), height);
  }
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I am experiencing the same.

Comment: I haven ot unfortunately